# Minimum number of double or triple flips to make a binary string all 1s

Tags: python, algorithm

I just completed a coding interview and I am stumped on a question in it. Although the test is already over, I still really want to know how this question can be solved.

**Problem:** Given a binary string (containing only `"1"` or `"0"`), find the minimum number of flips required to get a binary string of all `"1"`s.

- When a flip is performed, the value at that index will go from `"0"` to `"1"` or `"1"` to `"0"`.
- The only flips you are allowed to perform are either doubles or triples. Meaning that when a flip is performed, it must be performed on either two or three adjacent indices.

**Example:**

- For the binary string `"1010"`, the minimum number of flips required is 2. `"1010"` => `"1001"` => `"1111"` (end)
- For `"10001"`, minimm number of flips required is 1. `"10001"` => `"11111"` (end)

Comment: What was your attempt/intuition/thought process? Did you try a brute force solution first or consider which algorithmic paradigm this problem might fall into? What sort of time complexity are they expecting (if they told you and you asked)?

Comment: @ggorlen I figured that its a recursion problem, but I could not think of how to implement it (probably due to lack of practice) and how to determine a termination condition if there is no possible solution. There was no time complexity stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can brute-force it using recursion by performing flips on the first 2/3 characters and adding the result of recursing with the next positions:

```
def minFlips(s):
     if "0" not in s:      return 0  # all 1s, no flip needed
     if s in ("00","000"): return 1  # last flip for whole string
     
     def flip(n): # flip 1st n bits
          return s[:n].translate({48:49,49:48})+s[n:]
     
     result = [float('inf')] # track minimum flips
     if s.startswith("0"):   # must flip if starting with a zero
         if len(s)>2:        # first 2 + recursion
             result.append(1+minFlips(flip(2)[1:])) 
         if len(s)>3:        # first 3 + recursion
             result.append(1+minFlips(flip(3)[1:])) 
     else: # starts with "1"
         result.append(minFlips(s[1:])) # 0 flip + recursion
         if "0" in s[:2]: # can flip zero at 2nd position
             result.append(1+minFlips(flip(2))) # first 2 + recursion
         if "0" in s[:3]: # can flip zero at 2nd or 3rd position
             result.append(1+minFlips(flip(3))) # first 3 + recursion
     return min(result)

print(minFlips("1010"))       # 2
print(minFlips("10001"))      # 1
print(minFlips("1010110101")) # 4
```

*To optimize this, you can use memoization, or add the `@lru_cache()` decorator (from functools)*