# minimum flips to get a binary string af all ones

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, greedy

Problem: Given a binary string (containing only "1" or "0"), find the minimum number of flips required to get a binary string of all "1"s.

When a flip is performed, the value at that index will go from "0" to "1" or "1" to "0".
The only flips you are allowed to perform are either doubles or triples. Meaning that when a flip is performed, it must be performed on either two or three adjacent indices.
Example:

For the binary string "1010" the minimum number of flips required is 2. "1010" => "1001" => "1111" (end)
For "10001", minimm number of flips required is 1. "10001" => "11111" (end)

The problem has already been discussed in one of the posts at StackOverflow. But the logic has not been discussed properly. This is the only solution present there and the explanation is not enough to understand it properly. Can somebody please explain the logic behind the solution
or any other way of doing this problem.

```
    def minFlips(s):
     if "0" not in s:      return 0  # all 1s, no flip needed
     if s in ("00","000"): return 1  # last flip for whole string
     
     def flip(n): # flip 1st n bits
          return s[:n].translate({48:49,49:48})+s[n:]
     
     result = [float('inf')] # track minimum flips
     if s.startswith("0"):   # must flip if starting with a zero
         if len(s)>2:        # first 2 + recursion
             result.append(1+minFlips(flip(2)[1:])) 
         if len(s)>3:        # first 3 + recursion
             result.append(1+minFlips(flip(3)[1:])) 
     else: # starts with "1"
         result.append(minFlips(s[1:])) # 0 flip + recursion
         if "0" in s[:2]: # can flip zero at 2nd position
             result.append(1+minFlips(flip(2))) # first 2 + recursion
         if "0" in s[:3]: # can flip zero at 2nd or 3rd position
             result.append(1+minFlips(flip(3))) # first 3 + recursion
     return min(result)

print(minFlips("1010"))       # 2
print(minFlips("10001"))      # 1
print(minFlips("1010110101")) # 4
```

Can somebody please make things easier for me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: This doesn't seems to be java code but python one

Comment: Why is this tagged java? Maybe you should make things easier for the ones you expect help from by actually tagging the appropriate language you want help in.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I'm not very much familiar with python that's why I thought somebody could answer it in Java or c++ and that would be easier for me to understand.

Comment: Could you provide the link where you found this code?

Comment: yeah sure -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70228466/interview-question-binary-string-problem

Comment: What isn't clear about that solution? They explain that it's just a recursive brute forcing of all possibilities -- for every index, try a double or triple flip, then recurse on that subproblem. If it's not clear, it's usually best to leave a comment on that answer asking for more explanation -- you can do this at 50 rep.

Comment: It is not your question, but please note that (if I am not wrong), a simple procedure is possible, with a better efficiency (O(n)) than brute-force. One issue is that I cannot answer the other question, as  I don't know Python (only C/C++).

Comment: No problem at all I know C++. I will edit and change the the tag from java to c++. I just want an efficient solution and a better way to do it

Comment: You can use breadth-first-search. For code example please add more test cases with expected results.

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm:**

The result in independent from the order of the flips.
Moreover, performing 3 flips in equivalent to 1 flip.

Therefore, we can start from  the beginning and perform the operations iteratively.
If one element is equal to `0`, then this element and the next one must be flipped.
However, we have the choice for the element of index `i + 2`: we can flip it or not.

As a result, this last element is in an indetermined state `X`, either `0`or `1` according to a decision that we can pospone.

If at index `i`, we meet an `X`, then no flip is needed.

This procedure cannot be applied on the last element (index `n-1`).
For this last element, if the previous element (index `n-2`) is in state `X`, then only 1 additional flip is needed.
However, if it is not the case (then in state `1`), then two additional flips are needed. (`110` -> `111` needs 2 flips).

Complexity: O(n), faster than brute-force.

**Code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//  3-state (soft) inversion
// 0 -> 1
//  1 -> 0
/// x -> X

char soft_invers (char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case ('0'): return '1';
        case ('1'): return '0';
        
        default: return 'X';
    }
    return 'X';
}

int count_flips (std::string &input) {
    int count = 0;
    int n = input.size();
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    if (n == 1) {
        if (input[0] == '1') return 0;
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i) {
        if (input[i] == '0') {
            count++;
            input[i+1] = soft_invers(input[i+1]);
            if ((i+2) < n) input[i+2] = 'X';
        }
    }
    if (input[n-1] == '0') {
        if (input[n-2] == 'X') count++;
        else count += 2;
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> input = {"1010", "10001"};
    for (std::string &s: input) {
        std::cout << s << " : ";
        auto ans = count_flips(s);
        std::cout << ans << " flips\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Damien. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Comment: You welcome. If this answer fulfills your needs (take time to check it), you can accept it (or accept a better one if posted in the future).

Comment: can you please explain with an example why performing 3 flips is equivalent to 1 flip.

Comment: 3 flips: `0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 1` and 1 flip `0 -> 1`. Did you test this code?